changing the power levels of my WiFi card
How do I change the power levels (mW) of my WiFi card on Windows 10? Are there any tools out there for windows that let's me change the operating power levels of my WiFi card? Since Windows doesn't provide any options for changing the power levels

This is usually a function defined in the driver. Have you checked in Device Manager for the wireless device?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

yeah, but in the power management tab, nothing that lets me change the power levels appears
